# Need to get a Logic App connector which can get filepath and filename from the message queue

Tags: logic, azure-logic-apps

Need to get a Logic App connector which can get file-path and file-name from the message queue Connector -"When a message arrives (using peek lock model)",And further call data factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your message in in json type, if not please let me know. If you want to get the key value in the json message, you need `Parse JSON` action then get the value.

And the message is encoded with base64, so the `Parse JSON` input content should be `decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])`, after this you will be able to get the value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  @ George Chen I will try to do what you have said now.
But before that I will like to convey for your message. Please find the inline answers to your post.

Suppose your message in in json type - Yes JSON.
If you want to get the key value in the json message, you need Parse JSON action then get the value - I'm already using that now Thank you.!

And the message is encoded with base64 - Correct.

So the Parse JSON input content should be decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData']), after this you will be able to get the value - So here your trying to say that if i use the above code for parse JSON with  additional Connector - "Input variable" i can able to get the content of the queue as well able to pass the file name and path to the Data factory to kick start?

Please call/What's-App in #91 9444905898.
Please share your email ID.

Thanks,
Anirudh.

Comment: The variable action is used for test, you could pass the json value to connector action too.

Comment: Am getting a strange behavior with Logic App when the Message is put inside the queue the logic App runs 3 -4 times for a single message put.

Comment: Are you sure only one message in the queue and it runs well without exception?

Comment: George - Have you replied for  this message - " Am getting a strange behavior with Logic App when the Message is put inside the queue the logic App runs 3 -4 times for a single message put"?? For your response - Are you sure only one message in the queue and it runs well without exception?  yes only one message in the queue.! runs without any exception in the sense?  Can you really WhatsApp me now on the above number???

Comment: Sorry we don't use that, maybe I can have some test check if I could reproduce this problem. And will any messages trigger 3-4 timers?

Comment: Am not saying, Message is triggering 3-4 times...! The message sent to the queue which in-turn triggers Logic App to kick start, that triggers multiple runs... this happens when we send a single message in a queue Okay fine, np for which you don't use..for contacting..!! can you comment on the last this comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the same @ George..
The variable action is used for test, you could pass the json value to connector action too - I really didn't understand this line what are conveying..!